Terraform script for a centralised AWS Network Firewall and connect to existing vpcs via transit gateway
I need to create a new inspection network firewall VPC and monitor existing VPCs traffic from this. I need to connect the inspection VPC using transit gateway.
I created this via console but I couldn't ping because I got the routing wrong. So, i need a simple terraform solution to create this.

Your question reads like you are asking us to either provide some third-party solution, or write all the code for you to basically do your job for you. Both of those things are considered off-topic for this site. If you are working on a Terraform template for this, and have a specific question about that, post that question here.
